# Hybrid Encrypt in React and Decrypt in Java

Tags: javascript, java, encryption

I have been stuck in a long time. I am using [Hybrid Crypto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hybrid-crypto-js) library in React Native to encrypt the message. Both public and private key are in PEM format.

```
let crypt = new Crypt({rsaStandard: 'RSA-OAEP'});  
let encrypted = crypt.encrypt(publicKey, "This is a message");  
return JSON.parse(encrypted).cipher;
```

This is the code I use to decrypt in Java. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.txedo.com/blog/java-read-rsa-keys-pem-file/) to read private key from pem file using bouncycastle library.

```
String str = "M2vFz/28sWhwAK4rGmnFAPRORRTlfa+XYpHFWQsi0bo=";
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privateKey = generatePrivateKey(factory, RESOURCES_DIR + "private-key.pem");

Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

byte[] decryptOut = decryptCipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(str));
System.out.println(new String(decryptOut));
```

I've been trying many ways, the private key works fine when I decrypt in React but with Java I keep getting javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error.

---

**Updated Solution**
Because I'm using hybrid crypto so it will include RSA + AES
Flow in frondend: Using AES key to encrypt text => Using public RSA key to encrypt AES key. Then you send everything you need to decrypt (encrypted AES key, Iv, and cipher text)

```
let crypt = new Crypt({rsaStandard: 'RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5',aesIvSize: 16});
let encrypted = crypt.encrypt(publicKey, str);
const encryptedObj = JSON.parse(encrypted);
return Object.values(encryptedObj.keys)[0] + ',' + encryptedObj.iv + ',' + encryptedObj.cipher;
```

Flow in java: Using RSA private key to decrypt AES key => Using AES key + Iv to decrypt cipher text

```
PrivateKey privateKey = generatePrivateKey();
Cipher decryptCipher=Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    
byte[] keyb = decryptCipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(AESkey));
SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(keyb, "AES");
IvParameterSpecivspec = new IvParameterSpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(iv));
    
decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, ivspec);
byte[] decryptOut = decryptCipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText));
return new String(decryptOut);
```

Comment: In the JavaScript code you seem to apply OAEP. `Cipher.getInstance("RSA")` in the Java code does not specify the padding, so the provider-dependent default padding is used (which is often PKCS#1 v1.5 padding or no padding). So you should specify the padding explicitly in the Java code. Also, the OAEP parameters must match (e.g. OAEP and MGF1 digests).

Comment: Also, the JavaScript library used implements *hybrid* encryption with (by default) AES for the symmetric part. I don't see anything about AES in your Java code.

Comment: On the Java side you have to do the following for decryption: First decrypt the encrypted AES key with RSA. Then decrypt the ciphertext with AES-CBC. All required data is contained in `encrypted`: IV, encrypted AES key and the ciphertext.

Comment: @Topaco thank you very much for that. It's very late in my place rn, so I'll keep doing and updating this tomorrow

Comment: I honestly don't know why people would default to the software-only Bouncy if the functionality is already in the much better tested and optimized Java libraries. Funny enough, because you just add the provider without specifying it directly in `getInstance` it is most likely not even used.